# OneDrive API createUploadSession "API not found"

Tags: api, onedrive

According to the [onedrive api docs](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm#create-an-upload-session) to upload large files to OneDrive, first you create an upload session, then you send the fragments.  That all makes sense, but for some reason it's telling me that my request is invalid when I try the `createUploadSession` call to start the process.

Following the documentation, it says the request uri must follow this pattern: `POST /drive/root:/{path_to_item}:/createUploadSession`

request:

```
method: 'POST'
uri: 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/testfile-lg-1488040561730.bin:/createUploadSession
headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer .....' }
```

response:

```
status: 400
{ error: { code: 'invalidRequest', message: 'API not found' } }
```

I've tried various combinations of `createUploadSession` all lowercase, all uppercase, etc.  It's perhaps worth noting that the [small file <4MB simple file upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm) is working just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OneDrive API documentation was recently updated to refer to Microsoft Graph, which has a slightly different syntax. If you are calling the OneDrive API, as it looks like in your sample, you need to modify the call slightly by adding the "oneDrive." namespace to the action name.

`/oneDrive.createUploadSession`

We're working on updating the docs to make this more clear. There are more details here: https://dev.onedrive.com/direct-endpoint-differences.htm